# (Easy) I'm harder on the outside than on the inside

Tags: riddle

I'm usually born in the heat, I also guarantee that my lineage is at least as old as yours.

I have so many cousins, some are brown, others are white. We're all so different. Heck, we even come in dozens of different shapes!

Some of my cousins are a bit squared, I really like them.

Although some of my other cousins are a bit like dicks. They're french.

Best part? I'm never out of fashion.

And despite my conception depending a lot on where you live, I guarantee that someone's going to butter me to get maximum favour points.

*PS: I made a mistake, just forgot one Letter in one word!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are

> bread.
>
>  Some breads are white, some are wheat, which is brown,
>  and some are pumpernickel, which is really dark.
>
>  Bread loaves come in different shapes, some are square, like sandwich
>  bread, some are round, some are long and skinny like a French baguette.
>
>  Many people put butter on bread to get maximum flavour.
>  The forgotten letter, 'l', goes in favour, to get the flavour mentioned
>  above.